# Can't install my pro font awesome for my react project?

Tags: reactjs, npm, installation, font-awesome

I have a small error, I was trying to follow the guide that FontAwesome website gave to install their packages exactly, but suddenly an error shows up as always.

So he is what I did :

first I tapped this command :

> npm config set "@fortawesome:registry" https://npm.fontawesome.com/

Second I tapped this :

> npm config set "//npm.fontawesome.com/:_authToken" myToken

Everything is fine, I tapped this :

> npm install --save-dev @fortawesome/fontawesome-pro

but an error, here it is :

```
npm ERR! path C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\talkstats\node_modules\.staging\@fortawesome\fontawesome-pro-40c9a865\webfonts\fa-regular-400.ttf
npm ERR! code EPERM
npm ERR! errno -4048
npm ERR! syscall unlink
npm ERR! Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\talkstats\node_modules\.staging\@fortawesome\fontawesome-pro-40c9a865\webfonts\fa-regular-400.ttf'
npm ERR!  [OperationalError: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\talkstats\node_modules\.staging\@fortawesome\fontawesome-pro-40c9a865\webfonts\fa-regular-400.ttf'] {
npm ERR!   cause: [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Dell\Desktop\Learn\symfprojs\talkstats\node_modules\.staging\@fortawesome\fontawesome-pro-40c9a865\webfonts\fa-regular-400.ttf'] {
npm ERR!     errno: -4048,
npm ERR!     code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!     syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!     path: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Learn\\symfprojs\\talkstats\\node_modules\\.staging\\@fortawesome\\fontawesome-pro-40c9a865\\webfonts\\fa-regular-400.ttf'
npm ERR!   },
npm ERR!   stack: "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Learn\\symfprojs\\talkstats\\node_modules\\.staging\\@fortawesome\\fontawesome-pro-40c9a865\\webfonts\\fa-regular-400.ttf'",
npm ERR!   errno: -4048,
npm ERR!   code: 'EPERM',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'unlink',
npm ERR!   path: 'C:\\Users\\Dell\\Desktop\\Learn\\symfprojs\\talkstats\\node_modules\\.staging\\@fortawesome\\fontawesome-pro-40c9a865\\webfonts\\fa-regular-400.ttf',
npm ERR!   parent: 'talkstats'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It's possible that the file was already in use (by a text editor or antivirus),
npm ERR! or that you lack permissions to access it.
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator (though this is not recommended).

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Dell\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-30T03_35_04_582Z-debug.log
```

I don't know how to solve it. Any help would much appreciated.

Comment: have you tried giving the permissions to the file as above mentioned ?

Comment: have you tried to do sudo npm ...?

Comment: I dont use linux, so no, I did not try sudo.

Comment: No, I dd not give permission, is there a way to solve this by one commandline or I have to do it the hard way ?